# What do I do after "Defending the Rift"?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What do I do after the Defending the Rift quest in Abyssal Depths? Legionnaire Nazgrim jumped into the vortex and I am left alone on the ledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the Shaman got pulled down by the tentacle, he mentioned that thrall must be informed of the event. I thought naturally i have to return to orgrimmar to find him. I went back to the horde ship in shimmering expanse where an NPC is there to give me a quest to report back to orgrimmar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to talk to the only person beside you and he'll send you in as well. If there is no quest giver beside you, it's caused you've run into a bug, some people [here](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=26194/defending-the-rift#comments) are saying you can swim away then back and he's there.

Comment: I turned in the "Defending the Rift" and then jumped in the vortex after Nazgrim. Reached TOT entrance and nothing else I can do. That was my problem.